# In a rectangle $ABCD$ where $AB = 6$ , $BC = 3$ , point $P$ is chosen on $AB $ such that $\angle APD = 2 \angle CPB$. Find $AP$.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, problem-solving

> In a rectangle $ABCD$ where $AB = 6$ , $BC = 3$ , point $P$ is chosen on $AB $ such that $\angle APD = 2 \angle CPB$. Find $AP$.

**What I Tried**: Here is a picture :-

[image]

You can see I tried angle-chasing, but that really did not lead me to any useful info. Also I tried Pythagoras theorem, taking $AP = k$ and $PB = (6 - k)$ gives :-
$$k^2 + 9 = AP^2$$
$$(6 - k)^2 + 9 = PC^2$$
And that is $3$ variables in $2$ equations, so I need to find another value before trying this.

I think the fact that $AD = \frac{AB}{2}$ should be used somehow, maybe by some construction or something. Also in Geogebra I saw that $\angle APD = 65.7^\circ$ , $\angle CPB = 32.85^\circ$ , which are $2$ odd-looking angles, and $AP$ came to be $1.35$ .

Can anyone help me how is this the case? Thank You.

Comment: Do you know that $ \sin 2 \theta = 2 \sin \theta \cos \theta$? If yes, can that be applied?

Comment: I am weak at trigonometry so I am probably hearing it for the first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a=AP$ be the unknown to be found, we are trying to write an equation that $a$ should satisfy.

Let $Q$ be the point of intersection of the angle bisector of $\hat P$ in $\Delta APD$ with the opposite side $AD$ in this triangle. So $PQ$ divides this angle $\hat P$ in two angles of measure $x$, notation as in the OP. Then we have successively:

- $PD$ is $\sqrt{3^2+a^2}$, Pythagoras.
- $\Delta APQ\sim\Delta BPC$, so we obtain a formula for $AQ$ in terms of $a$, since $AQ:a=BC:(6-a)$. Explicitly, $AQ=3a/(6-a)$.
- This gives also $QD=AD-AQ=3-AQ$ in terms of $a$. Explicitly, $QD=(18-6a)/(6-a)$.
- We write now the angle bisector theorem in $\Delta APD$:
  $$
  \frac{QD}{QA}=\frac {PD}{PA}\ .
  $$
  this is the needed equation. Making things explicit, the resulted equation is:
  $$
  \frac{18-6a}{3a}=\frac{\sqrt{9+a^2}}{a}\ .
  $$
  We simplify with $a>0$, get $6-2a=\sqrt{9+a^2}$. So $6-2a>0$ (i.e. $a<3$), and
  $$
  (6-2a)^2 = 9+a^2\ .
  $$
  This is $a^2-8a+9=0$, the two roots are $4\pm 7$, and we pick the one $<3$, which is $4-\sqrt 7$.

Comment: Great solution without trigonometry.

Answer (score 2):

$$\tan 2x=\frac{3}{k},\tan x=\frac{3}{6-k}$$ now use $$\tan 2x=\frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2 x}$$

Comment: Any solution without trigonometry and using elementary geometry? :) .

Comment: @Anonymous let me think

Comment: @Anonymous Just use the fact that $sin^2x = 1 - cos^2x$ and $sin2x = 2 sinx \, cosx$. Given how the angle is, I doubt a geomoetry solution.

Comment: Ok, and solving use @AlbusDumbledore's method, I am getting $k = 4 \pm \sqrt{7}$ , is this right? Why am I getting $2$ solutions?

Comment: @Anonymous, Take the solution with positive value as negative solution can be ignored.

Comment: @IAMIRONMAN both the solutions have positive values.

Comment: You pick the solution which is within the rectangle. (minus sign)

Comment: @MathLover that means the other solution lies outside the rectangle?

Comment: Typically when you take square root, you will get plus and minus. You need to check which is/are the feasible solution for your case.

Comment: @Anonymous $4+\sqrt{7}>6$

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore yes I noticed it, so $4 - \sqrt{7}$ is the answer. Also that is nearly equal to $1.35$ which I found to be same in Geogebra too.

Comment: @Anonymous there is a way to solve without trigonometry but you may have to solve 6 equations and they are not nice (i may have to spend a whole day to solve them!)